# RegId required: java.io.FileNotFoundException: GCMRegId.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)

Tags: java, push-notification

I have written a program to implement Google Cloud Messaging in android using jsp . Got the reference from here (http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications/)
      I am not able to run on server when i try to run program in my eclipse it gives me GCMRegId.txt missing error.
      Here are the code:

```
 GCMNotification.java

@WebServlet("/GCMNotification")
public class GCMNotification extends HttpServlet {

private static final String GOOGLE_SERVER_KEY = "AIzaSyDA5dlLInMsasJEUTIHV0u7maB82MCasdU";
static final String MESSAGE_KEY = "message";    

public GCMNotification() {
    super();
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request, response);

}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


    Result result = null;

    String share = request.getParameter("shareRegId");

    // GCM RedgId of Android device to send push notification
    String regId = "APA91bG6cLX8OYyZDRypuRq6uodZ9PuMfiql9k6K66i9hZFnS5xr-QmT13nRozGQ10KXNmcMqbsLCVUIS9joGiOPasdfghjklp_AmH2iNs1YVqY3IYzgHoQ";
    if (share != null && !share.isEmpty()) {
        regId = request.getParameter("regId");
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("GCMRegId.txt");
        writer.println(regId);
        writer.close();
        request.setAttribute("pushStatus", "GCM RegId Received.");
        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp")
                .forward(request, response);
    } else {

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                    "GCMRegId.txt"));
            regId = br.readLine();
            br.close();
            String userMessage = request.getParameter("message");
            Sender sender = new Sender(GOOGLE_SERVER_KEY);
            Message message = new Message.Builder().timeToLive(30)
                    .delayWhileIdle(true).addData(MESSAGE_KEY, userMessage).build();
            System.out.println("regId: " + regId);
            result = sender.send(message, regId, 1);
            request.setAttribute("pushStatus", result.toString());
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
            request.setAttribute("pushStatus",
                    "RegId required: " + ioe.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            request.setAttribute("pushStatus", e.toString());
        }
        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp")
                .forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

JSP page:
index.jsp

```
  <head>
 </head>
 <body>

<h1>Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) Server in Java</h1>
 <%
String pushStatus = "";
Object pushStatusObj = request.getAttribute("pushStatus");

if (pushStatusObj != null) {
    pushStatus = pushStatusObj.toString();
}
 %>
<form action="GCMNotification" method="post">

    <div>
          <textarea rows="2" name="message" cols="23"
          placeholder="Message to transmit via GCM"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Send Push Notification via GCM" />
    </div>
</form>
<p>
    <h3>
        <%=pushStatus%>
    </h3>
</p>
```

It always gives me error like
     RegId required: java.io.FileNotFoundException: GCMRegId.txt (The system   cannot find the file specified) 
     how can i resolve that error???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Guys i solved that problem. GCMRegId.txt file generate automatically. Does not make manually that file.

Or if you dont want to make GCMRegId.txt file simply remove from your code and and pass the DeviceId to the regID(string) and remove unused code.

you will get your output.
thanks.

Comment: but how do you solved your error I'm getting the same error and also I'm not able to push message from android device to GCM and from jsp to android device please help

Comment: Just remove all code which contains GCMRegid.txt and put the manually regId and change the code with it.
  String regId = "ID over here";
Sender sender = new Sender(GOOGLE_SERVER_KEY);
    Message message = new Message.Builder().timeToLive(30)
      .delayWhileIdle(true).addData(MESSAGE_KEY, userMessage).build();

result = sender.send(message, regId, 1);
request.setAttribute("pushStatus", result.toString());

Comment: hava you deployed this code on App Engine as this working fine on local host as a Java project but how to map this in App engine any idea ?

Comment: check this out. http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications/  i hope u ll get your ans.

Comment: I've already read whole the tutorial but they deploy web application on local server instead App Engine